# How to enable Edit Source button in latest versions of Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

Was 'Edit Source' button removed from latest Orbeon versions? I was looking at Orbeon 4.7 and I couldn't find/enable it anymore. 
I was wondering if it was just disabled and I even tried adding the property:

```
 <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fb.menu.edit-source" value="true"/>
```

After it, it still did not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it hasn't been removed but it has moved. See screeenshot.

[image]